# Big integer is not being rounded

Tags: javascript, rounding, bignum

Using the following library: 
http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber

my big integer is not being rounded.

My code is the following:

```
x=1234.56;
y = new BigNumber(x);
document.write("<br>1 "+Math.round(x)  +"<br>");
document.write("<br>2 "+y.round()+"<br>"); // '1235'
document.write("<br>3 "+y.round(1)+"<br>"); // '1235.6'
document.write("<br>4 "+y.round(2)+"<br>"); // '1235.56'
document.write("<br>5 "+y.round(10)+"<br>"); // '1235.56'
document.write("<br>6 "+y.round(0, 1)+"<br>"); // '1234'
document.write("<br>7 "+y.round(0, 6)+"<br>"); // '1235'
document.write("<br>8 "+y.round(1, 1)+"<br>"); // '1234.5'
document.write("<br>9 "+y.round(1, BigNumber.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)+"<br>"); // '1234.6'
```

I am receiving the following output:

> 1 1235
>
> 2 1234.56
>
> 3 1234.56
>
> 4 1234.56
>
> 5 1234.56
>
> 6 1234.56
>
> 7 1234.56
>
> 8 1234.56
>
> 9 1234.56

Comment: @JonathanM There is a `.round()` method [here](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#round)

Comment: @JonathanM you're only looking at class methods, not instance methods.

Comment: Sorry, got my eyes crossed. :)

Comment: @JonathanM no worries.

Comment: this first link shows this though `BigNumber.round(void)` at the bottom of the page

Comment: beacause i want to round a big number that math.round doent support it. 
an I agree with Eli Sadoff, .round() method exist

Comment: Please update your question to should what your expected output is.

Comment: I'd say the expected output could be assumed, for `.round(1)` it's `1234.6`, for `.round(2)` it's, `1234.56`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The library you're using ask for precision and round type when you create your `BigNumber`, the `round()` method didn't take any parameter.

So you should change your code where:

```
y = new BigNumber(x);
```

To

```
y = new BigNumber(x, 0, 1);
```

Comment: The `.round()` method takes parameters. Look [here](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#round)

Comment: Not the code of the link he posted, where the doc in the page have: `BigNumber.round(void): void`